# How app.scss knows that ~foo is a foo directory inside node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I have a Laravel project with `app.scss` located in `resources/assets/sass/frontend/`.

The `node_modules` is in the root directory.

Inside `app.scss` I have:

`@import '../../../../node_modules/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css';`

however I can replace this with:

`@import '~daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css';`

and still the file can be found by both my IDE and `npm` when I run `npm run dev`.

Obviously the second approach is much cleaner and I want to stick with it but **where is the logic that knows that tilde means going 4 levels up in the directory structure and the entering `node_modules`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is webpack sass-loader. [Documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#user-content-imports) says:

> Thus you can import your Sass modules from node_modules. Just prepend them with a ~ to tell webpack that this is not a relative import:
>
> ```
> @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
> ```

IDE usually aware about such webpack features.

If it isn't a webpack you probably using other kind of compiler which most likely repeat that behaviour.

Comment: I do use webpack. Thank you Arseniy for an explanation. 